# how to get left value without initializing in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically I need to identify, how far is an element from left corner in pixel while the element style in css is `left:auto`

e.g:

```
<span id='span1'>
   <span id='child1'>hello there </span>
   <span id='child2'>get left value of this DOM</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#child1{
  background:red;  
}
#child2{
  background: green;
}
```

is there anyway to find out the left value of `child2` in either javascript or jquery?

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/7wp5fc6r/

Comment: You may can try with jQuery offset() method which returns you top and left positions of current element.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript you can get this value and more with getBoundingClientRect() [this is the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) of this method, this is an example:

```js
const childTwo = document.getElementById("child2");

const leftSpace = childTwo.getBoundingClientRect().left;

console.log("space in pixels", leftSpace)
```

```css
#child1{
  background:red;  
}
#child2{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<span id='span1'>
  <span id='child1'>hello there </span>
  <span id='child2'>get left value of this DOM</span>
</span>
```

Comment: I believe above method doesn't get the distance from parent node but the whole html body

Comment: in this case you can get this distance with the difference in the left distance of parent and child, would be like `parent.getBoundingClientRect().left - child.getBoundingClientRect().left`  = left parent and child distance